# qTip jQuery version conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, versioning, qtip

Is it standard practice to hold an entire project at a certain release of jQuery until I can fix one measly bug?

details:
I'm using an older version of [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) because that is what works with jQuery 1.4.2 (the current release when I started the project). It's important to note that the release candidate of qTip [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111365/jquery-fullcalendar-and-qtip/3639817#3639817) with the currently stable jQuery.

A bug showed up in my qTip functionality where the tool-tips starting animating themselves in from off-screen whereas they should pop-up on the element on mouse-over.

Needless to say, I thought I had broke something but eventually noticed that jQuery had moved up a notch so I moved back to jQuery 1.4.2 and viola, tool-tips work as expected.

Now I don't know what to do; I want to keep the project at the current and stable jQuery library but I'm not sure how to debug for something like this.

Also, I don't feel I should be submitting bugs to an old version of an app, either, but maybe I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On qTip library replace the line

`if(typeof $(this).data('qtip') == 'object')`

with

`if($(this).data('qtip') !== null && typeof $(this).data('qtip') == 'object')`

Good Luck!

Comment: i found this line: if(typeof $(this).data('qtip') === 'object' && $(this).data('qtip'))