# How to capture dayclick events on non empty days fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on a project and I need to know if there is a way to capture [dayClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) events specifically in days with already set events, in such a way that I can add more events using a popup.

Comment: add code snippet. check my basic answer which might help you.

Comment: it is more of avoiding confusion between day and event clicks in such a way i edit an existing event if clicked, or add a new one if and empty space in the same day is clicked, without needing an "add event" button

Comment: share exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [dayClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) Method. Below is the Code Snippet and I suggest [qTip](http://qtip2.com/) for Full Calendar PopUp.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

    // change the day's background color just for fun
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

  }
});
```

Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639817/1533666) for Full Calendar and qTip Integration.